# Evaluating integral with given condition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\left[1 + {\rm f}\left(x\right)\right]x
+
\int_{1}^{x}{\rm f}\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t\right\}\,{\rm d}x =1
$$
Then value of $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}{\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x =\ {\large ?}}$.

No idea how to solve. I would be glad if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider changing order of integration in $$\int_0^1\int_1^x f(t)\,dt\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\int f(x)$, the indefinite integral. Then you can write everything in terms of $g$ as
$$
\int_0^1 x f(x) dx = g(1)-\int_0^1 g(x) dx$$

$$\int_1^x f(t) dt = g(x)-g(1)$$
$$ \int _0 ^1 dx = 1$$
Now combine them to get the final answer.

The answer is $1$ and does not depend on $f(x)$.